# **INVALID** Test fails but ball is still green

Tags: jenkins, xunit

**Edit:** Please see my own answer

With the xUnit-plugin in Jenkins I have configured **Post-build Actions > Publish xUnit test result report > Failed Tests** to set the **Build Status** as red, with a treshold of 1 (set in the **Total** field). The other fields are left empty.

But although having a test that fails, the status ball stays green. Worth mentioning is that the xUnit-plugin detects the failure. It is listed under **Latest Test Result** and also in the **Test Result Trend** graph.

Along with the configuration form the is a description stating: "..A build is considered as unstable or failure if the new or total number of failed tests exceeds the specified thresholds.". But seems strange, 1 will never exceed 1. Are you not allowed to set it as failure for a single failed test case? I can not recall seeing this before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sometimes ones brain certainly malfunctions.

1 may not exceed 1 but it exceeds 0 for sure. I think I need to go on vacation.